# In ElasticSearch how to recover data from replicas?

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

A folder (index) have been deleted from a node : /data3/data/es/esdartyprd/nodes/0/indices/enc_idx/2/index )

I can see that data are missed for primary shard in this node (node1) => 
for this index , here what gives me the command curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards

```
enc_idx         2 p STARTED    57824815 28.8gb 10.135.8.201 HDPESPRD1
enc_idx         2 r STARTED    57824815 36.5gb 10.135.8.202 HDPESPRD2
enc_idx         2 r STARTED    57824815 36.5gb 10.135.10.15 HDPESPRA1
enc_idx         2 r STARTED    57824815 36.5gb 10.135.8.203 HDPESPRD3
enc_idx         2 r UNASSIGNED
```

You can see that data are missed in the node1 which is master ! And still have problem to assign data to node4

Any possibility to recover or replicate missed data from replicate shards ? Is that done automatically? Any solutions to assign the shard which is not assigned ? In the log I find an error that a file is corrupted from this folder :

```
 [enc_idx][2] Corrupted index [corrupted_1ytPPpKkTZCGG_zQcbBG-w] caused by: CorruptIndexException[codec footer mismatch: actual footer=1063427 vs expected footer=-1071082520 (resource: NIOFSIndexInput(path="/data3/data/es/esdartyprd/nodes/0/indices/enc_idx/2/index/_3gv6_es090_0.pos"))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following -

- Shutdown the cluster.
- Set node `HDPESPRD2` as master eligible by setting `node.master:
  true`.
- Restart all nodes in cluster except node `HDPESPRD1` & `unassigned` node.

This will result in node `HDPESPRD2` becoming the new master. You can then rejoin the remaining nodes later after clearing their data folders. New replicas will be again created in them as soon as they join the cluster.